# Optimise two SQL queries and a list comprehension

Tags: python, django, optimization

I have those two models (simplified):

```
class Place(OrderedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, blank=True)
```

Say that there are ten instances of `Place`. But only five instances of `Team`. I want to return a list of booleans in the order of entries in `Place`, where `True` means that `Team.places` contains that place and `False` (obviously) means that it doesn't. The `Team.places` field has no particular order.

In the following example the `Team` have the instances of the first four `Place` objects and the last one in it's `places` field:

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

I solved this with this method on the Team model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    def done(self):
        """
        Returns a list of Booleans, one for each place
        in order. True means that the team has found the
        place. False, that they have not.
        """
        places = Place.objects.all()
        return [p in self.places.all() for p in places]
```

It works but seems highly inefficient. It make (I believe) two different SQL queries and then a list comprehension. Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

#### Solved

I ended up doing this:

```
def done(self):
    """
    Returns a list of Booleans, one for each place
    in order. True means that the team has found the
    place. False, that they have not.
    """
    sql = '''SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done
    FROM qrgame_place P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN qrgame_team_places TP
    ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s'''
    places = Place.objects.raw(sql, [self.id])
    for p in places:
        yield bool(p.done)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done
FROM myapp_place P
LEFT OUTER JOIN myapp_team_places TP
ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s
```

(You'll also need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to return the `Place` objects in the order you want, but since I can't see that part of your model, I can't tell what that clause ought to look like.)

I don't know how to express this query using Django's object-relational mapping system, but you can always run it using a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):

```
>>> sql = ''' ... as above ... '''
>>> places = Place.objects.raw(sql, [team.id])
>>> for p in places:
...     print p.id, bool(p.done)
...
1 True
2 True
3 False
```

Comment: Your loop at the end should be `[bool(p.done) for p in places]`

Comment: Oh, silly mistake to not catch. It was right in your code example. Work like a charm. I will, just for fun, time the different solution. But I would be surprised if this is not the mot optimized. Would it work on all major SQL-servers?

Comment: It's standard SQL so should run everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A more optimal solution would be:

```
def done(self):    
    places = Place.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    team_places = self.places.values_list('pk', flat=True)

    return [place in team_places for place in places]
```

Comment: Oh. Nice I don't have time just now. But will read up on on the documentation to understand why it's more optimized (I have a good guess what `values_list` does) and also time the different lookups.

Comment: I suggest `team_places = set(...)` so that the lookups are O(1).