# Can't implement ORDER BY clause in complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I tried to implement the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899701/optimise-two-sql-queries-and-a-list-comprehension). The answer did work but I figured out that I missed to implement an `ORDER BY` clause for the column `order` in the `qrgame_place` table (I've checked that the column really exist). But I can't get it to work. This is what my problem comes down to. This works:

```
sql = '''SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done
FROM qrgame_place P
LEFT OUTER JOIN qrgame_team_places TP
ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s
WHERE P.game_id = %s
'''
```

But this won't:

```
sql = '''SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done
FROM qrgame_place P
LEFT OUTER JOIN qrgame_team_places TP
ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s
WHERE P.game_id = %s
ORDER BY P.order ASC
'''
```

I tried to change place of the `ORDER BY` but it won't help.

The error Django is giving me in the template is:

```
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    near "order": syntax error
```

What am I not understanding about the SQL-language?

Comment: Not sure what client language this is, but please print out the "sql" string after it has been constructed.  Have tried that, and take the SQL string and execute through a SQL client tool?  Maybe you are missing a space between "%s" and "ORDER"?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQLite on dev-server (where the problem occured) and MySQL on production server. Found a solution. See my answer :) THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, which I should have catched myself before (doh) was that `order` of course is a reserved keyword i SQL and that triggered SYNTAX ERROR in sqlite even if I wrote `P.order`, I don't think the MySQL on the production server would have give me any problems(?). But this seems to work:

```
sql = '''SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done, P.`order` as ord
FROM qrgame_place P
LEFT OUTER JOIN qrgame_team_places TP
ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s
WHERE P.game_id = %s
ORDER BY ord
'''
```

Observe the special chars surrounding `order` on the first line in the query. I could (I believe) choose to not select P.order and just call it this way on the ORDER BY line. But I listen to other ansers and just includes it.

MySQL and SQLite takes this. Unsure about other DB:s.

Comment: One more reason to use exactly the same DBMS in development and production. And should anybody would have known that? Your original question didn't include a column named `order` (which is a very bad habit of naming in the first place - never ever use a reserved word as an identifier.

Comment: Yeah! My "production server" in this case is not really critical. It's for a game project of mine. I will have this in the back of my head, though. Also, in this case i used some elses Django model which implemented this field. So did not thought about this problem until now. And I don't think I bother forking this module, nor choose another. This works...

Answer (score 0):

Order is not in the SELECT so it can't be ordered by that.

Add it to the output list

```
sql = '''SELECT P.id, (TP.id IS NOT NULL) AS done, P.order
FROM qrgame_place P
LEFT OUTER JOIN qrgame_team_places TP
ON P.id = TP.place_id AND TP.team_id = %s
WHERE P.game_id = %s
ORDER BY P.order ASC
'''
```

Or order by another column such as id or done

Comment: Are you sure? I really didn't think it mattered. Which SQL dialects does it matter to? SQLite don't seem to be affected.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: I agree, this "restriction" sounds strange and sure isn't true for all DBMS: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a06be/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/feb2b/1

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY sorts the output. The field you're trying to order by isn't in the output, so the statement is invalid.

Comment: Not true: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a06be/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/feb2b/1